# Which one better to use Hibernate Transaction or Spring Transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

In my Project i am using Hibernate as well Spring and both can manage transaction here my question is that which will be good to manage the transaction in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring itself is not capable to start/commit/rollback a transaction; his purpose is to remove boiler plate code needed to manage transaction lifecyle and delegate to a persistence engine (Hibernate, JDBC, JPA and so on) the real start/commit/rollback.
Take this example:

```
Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
try
{
  doSomeStuff();
  tx.commit();
}
catch(HibernateException e)
{
  tx.rollback();
}
s.close();
```

This is standard (boiler plate) to execute operations under transaction (using Hibernate, if you need to switch to JPA you need to rewrite code).
With Spring you can use declarative way (AOP, via XML or using annotation) to remove standard code in this way:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeStuff()
{
  // your code
}
```

I'm using annotation for example and `@Transactional` is used to replace all boiler plate code above and you have another feature: switching to JPA is transparent because is just a configuration problem.
The question is really complex and the answer to your question is:
You can't "compare" Hibernate Transaction and Spring Transaction because they are two different things; Spring Transaction should be "Spring transaction support"

Comment: look good details explanation but one question in my mind if i am executing 10-12 queries and all queries are inter-dependable and if a query have any issue will the data will Rollback by only using @Transactional notation?

Comment: i did not get your last comment

Comment: Yes, data will be rollbacked by only using `@Transactional`: If `// your code` contains your 10-12 queries and one fails all previous commands are discarded; `@Transactional` apply to entire method

Answer (score 1):

Spring is the one that will allow you managing transactions in a *declarative* way (using AOP, configured globally or with `@Transactional` annotations). And if you're not using JTA, you'll configure it to delegate to Hibernate to handle transactions.

Use Spring to handle transactions.

Comment: Can it possible to explore your answer a bit more?

Comment: See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative and http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative. If you have a more concrete question, maybe I can answer it.